# Migration crashes after recreate() method

Tags: java, android, realm

Migration works rigth, but my app at some point have to restart (`recreate()`) to do interface stuff. At this point the app crashes because of migration:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{APP/APP.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Configurations cannot be different if used to open the same file. 
                                             Cached configuration: 
                                             realmFolder: /data/user/0/APP/files
                                             realmFileName : default.realm
                                             canonicalPath: /data/data/APP/files/default.realm
                                             key: [length: 0]
                                             schemaVersion: 0
                                             migration: null
                                             deleteRealmIfMigrationNeeded: false
                                             durability: FULL
                                             schemaMediator: io.realm.DefaultRealmModuleMediator@19c237a3
```

Migration snippet:

```
mRealmConfig = new RealmConfiguration.Builder(this)
        .schemaVersion(0)
        .migration(new Migration())
        .build();
realm = Realm.getInstance(mRealmConfig);
realm.close();
```

Migration class:

```
public class Migration implements RealmMigration {
@Override
public void migrate(final DynamicRealm realm, long oldVersion, long newVersion) {
    RealmSchema schema = realm.getSchema();

    // Migrate from version 0 to version 1
    if (oldVersion == 0) {
        RealmObjectSchema notificationSchema = schema.get("classTarget");

        notificationSchema
                .addField("something", Boolean.class, FieldAttribute.REQUIRED)
                .transform(new RealmObjectSchema.Function() {
                    @Override
                    public void apply(DynamicRealmObject obj) {
                        obj.set("something", true);
                    }
                });
        oldVersion++;
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you are creating the RealmConfiguration instance multiple times. Either try to keep it in a static field or use `Realm.setDefaultInstance(config) / Realm.getDefaultInstance()` instead.

The reason you are seeing the exception is because your RealmMigration class doesn't override `equals()/hashCode()`. That means our internal checks think that you have two different configurations because `new Migration().equals(new Migration()) == false`

Comment: Also note that you need to bump the schema version from 0 to correctly trigger the migration.